# How do I give a specific role permission to schedule emails of a saved search on NetSuite?

Tags: permissions, netsuite, administration

I want to have Email to appear, so that a user in a specific role can be able to send out email alerts when records are created/updated (as well as other email-related functionalities) without handing them over the Administrator role.

Usually, I would go to `Setup > Users/Roles > Edit`, I would naturally find the permissions settings for this specific role near here https://i.ibb.co/7KHLb2W/image.png near the bottom of the page.

I was wondering, out of these permission types below...

- Transactions
- Reports
- Lists
- Setup
- Custom Record

Which one do I select and what is the name of the specific permission?

As a form of early troubleshooting, I have already attempted to set the access level to "Edit" instead of "None" or "View" for the following permission types:

- Lists > Mail Merge
- Setup > Custom Center Tabs
- Transactions > Email Template

My initial suspicions are that they are in Transactions and Setup but I feel as if these can be wrong.

For clarification, here is what I am trying to achieve:

- Before: https://i.ibb.co/zQyf9Lx/before.png
- After: https://i.ibb.co/Kq1tdqz/after.png

(Whether or not "Email" appears before or after "Audit Trail" is irrelevant. As I only wanted it to be accessible to this specific role to make changes with.)

Any help is much well appreciated.

Comment: @Jdg50 the save/save as... button is irrelevant with what I want to have done. As marked by a green box, my only concern is the "Email" option being there for this particular role. Everything else is irrelevant with what I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission you need to add is Lists > Publish Search.  You will need to set it to Edit or Full.  Then the user will be able to access the Email tab where they can set alerts and schedules.  Keep in mind the user will also need permissions to access the transaction records that they are creating the searches for.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works like a charm. In my case, I've set it to Edit. I am always aware of permissions on a per-transaction record basis but this will reaffirm that this is always a consideration nonetheless.